# jquery selector for an element that needs escaped

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, escaping

I have the following element which is generated by some struts code which I am unable to change.

`<input type="hidden" name="versions[0].elements[0].description">`

I would typically use something like `$('input[name=XXX]');`

However as my name has special characters I need to be able to escape it. Any ideas?

Thanks
W

Comment: Are you sure you cannot change your some struts code? Which tag generates this hidden field?

Comment: Do you need this: `$("input[name='versions[0].elements[0].description']");`?

Comment: @VisionN yes it wasn't seeming to work.

Comment: versions[0].elements[0].description are variables or just a string?

Comment: @AleksandrM That name is generated internally by Struts to match the heirarchy of a form bean (a Java object), so it's impossible to change without changing the object structure in their web application. Assuming Struts, and not Struts2, it's generated using the [`<html:hidden>`](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-html.html#hidden) tag.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: So it possible to add `styleClass` attribute or it equivalent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between these different ways to escape square brackets inside jQuery selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573178/what-is-the-difference-between-these-different-ways-to-escape-square-brackets-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to wrap the name variable in quotes, like this:

```
$('input[name="versions[0].elements[0].description"]');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/RezXW/)

You don't need to escape in this case the attribute value is treated by jQuery internally as a string literal.

Comment: Thanks Rory .. this is what I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

From the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \

So in your case:

```
$('input[name="versions\\[0\\].elements\\[0\\].description"]');
```

Comment: This is incorrect. When using a string literal you don't need to escape: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/RezXW/1/

Answer (score 0):

if you have a pattern in the input name, you can use the `^=` to select name that start with something or `$=` to select the end or `*=` to select the input that contains something.
For instance:

```
 $('input[name$="description"]')
```

select the input that name end with description.

Answer (score 0):

Idea 1: add a css class to your input element, for example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="versions[0].elements[0].description" class="version-desc">
```

Then, to get it:

```
var $inputs = $("input.version-desc");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two backslashes before each special character.

e.g.

```
$('input[name=\\XXX\\]')
```